# JavaScript countdown timer not display button after reset

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to create html5 app that have a timer. After time end in 10 second, it will display a button. Supposed to be, once user click on the button, a popup will displayed and it will count the button click in a variable and reset the timer. The process will loop again. The issue is, after user click on the button, and after the timer finished countdown for second time, the button is not displaying.

Here is the Js codes:

```
<!-- Timer countdown -->
   <script type=text/javascript>
    var clicks = 0;
    function showTimer(selector, seconds) 
    {
        var startTime = Date.now();
        var interval;


        function showRemaining() 
        {
            var delta = Date.now() - startTime;     // milliseconds
            var deltaSeconds = delta / (1000);
                if (deltaSeconds < seconds) {
                        // display minutes remaining
                    $(selector).text(Math.round(seconds - deltaSeconds));
                        } else {
                            $(selector).text(0);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                                }
        }

    interval = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    showRemaining();
    }


    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            showTimer("#countdown", 10);

        });

    setTimeout(function() 
    {
    $("#proceed").show();
    }, 10000);     

    //when click button
    function onClick() {

        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("proceed").style.visibility="hidden";
        alert("Getting the message");
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

        showTimer("#countdown", 10);

    };

    </script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
    <br>
    <p ><span id="countdown"></span><br>
   Timer Here<br>
    <button type="button" id="proceed" onclick="onClick()">Click</button><br>
        <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: are you included jquery.js file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to show your button again, the way you did it , it's going to hide. remove the setTimeout since you know the end of your timer and also can repeat it.

```js
var clicks = 0;
var interval = -1;
function showTimer(selector, seconds) 
{
    var startTime = Date.now();
    
    function showRemaining() 
    {
        var delta = Date.now() - startTime;     // milliseconds
        var deltaSeconds = delta / (1000);
        if (deltaSeconds < seconds) {
            // display minutes remaining
            $(selector).text(Math.round(seconds - deltaSeconds));
        } else {
            $(selector).text(0);
            clearInterval(interval);
            $("#proceed").show(); // Look at here
        }
    }
    if( interval > -1 ) clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    showRemaining(); 
}

$(function() {
    showTimer("#countdown", 10);
});

//when click button
function onClick() {

    $("#proceed").hide();
    alert("Getting the message");
    $("#clicks").text(++clicks);

    showTimer("#countdown", 10);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<br>
<p >
  <span id="countdown"></span><br>
  Timer Here<br>
  <button type="button" id="proceed" onclick="onClick()">Click</button><br>
  <a id="clicks">0</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

include jquery file link,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I worked like a charm. Thank you so much. That help a lot.